# WHy select hangs => two UDP servers (Broadcast)

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, udp, broadcast

I'm trying to implement a server that will provide different data if accessed in Wlan or in eth (on the same port (mandatory)) so I build this code with select and everything but my select hangs indefinitely even if there is data comming (tested with the same app that only uses 1 udp server and don't "see" the difference). Any idea of what I'm doing wrong ? (I'm quite desperate)

```
#include<stdio.h>   
#include<string.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define BUFLEN 1024
#define PORT 8000   
using namespace std;
char *ipAddrFromInterface(char *apInterfaceName) //this function is not from me
{
    char *if_name = (char *) apInterfaceName;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    size_t if_name_len=strlen(if_name);
    if (if_name_len<sizeof(ifr.ifr_name)) {
        memcpy(ifr.ifr_name,if_name,if_name_len);
        ifr.ifr_name[if_name_len]=0;
    } else {
       printf("interface name is too long\n");
    }int fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    if (fd==-1) {
        printf("A => %s\n",strerror(errno));
    }if (ioctl(fd,SIOCGIFADDR,&ifr)==-1) {
        int temp_errno=errno;
        close(fd);
        printf("B => %s\n",strerror(temp_errno));
    }
    if (ioctl(fd,SIOCGIFADDR,&ifr)==-1) {
        int temp_errno=errno;
        close(fd);
       printf("C => %s\n",strerror(temp_errno));
    }
    close(fd);

    struct sockaddr_in* ipaddr = (struct sockaddr_in*)&ifr.ifr_addr;
    return inet_ntoa(ipaddr->sin_addr);
}

struct socketData
{
    int sock;
    sockaddr_in  socket;
    char *interfaceName;
};

void print(int i)
{
    printf("%d\n", i);
    fflush(stdout);
}

void server_receive_thread(vector<char*> aInterfaceList)
{
    int socketIndex = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in  localSock;
    int socketDescriptor; int socketLength;

    vector<socketData> aSockets;
    for(; socketIndex < aInterfaceList.size(); socketIndex++)
    {
        socketData socketD;
        char *apInterfaceName = aInterfaceList.at(socketIndex);
        if((socketDescriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
        {
            printf("can't listen on interface %s... sleeping\n", apInterfaceName);
        }
        else
        {
            memset(&localSock, 0,  sizeof(localSock));
            localSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
            localSock.sin_port = htons(PORT);

            inet_aton(ipAddrFromInterface(apInterfaceName), &localSock.sin_addr);

            setsockopt(socketDescriptor, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, apInterfaceName, sizeof(apInterfaceName));
            if(bind(socketDescriptor, (struct sockaddr *) &localSock, sizeof(localSock)) == -1)
            {
                printf("can't bind interface %s to listen on port %d... sleeping\n", apInterfaceName, PORT);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("bound to interface %s on port %d\n", apInterfaceName, PORT);
                socketD.sock = socketDescriptor;
                socketD.socket = localSock;
                socketD.interfaceName = apInterfaceName;
                aSockets.push_back(socketD);
            }
        }
    }

            fd_set master;
        int fdMax = 0;
        while(1)
        {
                FD_ZERO(&master);
                for(int iSock = 0; iSock < aSockets.size(); iSock++)
                {
                        socketData d = aSockets.at(iSock);
                        FD_SET(d.sock, &master);
                        if(fdMax = 0 || d.sock > fdMax)
                        {
                                fdMax = d.sock;
                        }
                }
                printf("fdmax is : ");
                print(fdMax);
                if(select(fdMax+1, &master, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1)
                        print(2);
                print(200);
                for(int iSock = 0; iSock < aSockets.size(); iSock++)
                {
                        socketData d = aSockets.at(iSock);
                        if(FD_ISSET(d.sock, &master))
                        {
                                print(3);
                        }
                }
                print(1);
        }


}

int main()
{
std::vector<char*>  interfaceList;
char *wlan = "wlan0";
interfaceList.push_back("wlan0");
interfaceList.push_back("eth0");
server_receive_thread(interfaceList);
return 0;
}
```

I'm building with :
 g++ -lpthread -g filename.cpp
On a raspberry pi

Thanks

## Edit

(I'm going to open a new thread about it)
Ok so I found part of the problem, I had to bind not on the ip address but on the broadcast (255.255.255.255) (I'm sorry I forget to mention that before)... however wile this works, it doesn't identify each interface so the app doesn't know how to interpret it

Actually :

```
#include<stdio.h>   
#include<string.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define BUFLEN 1024
#define PORT 8000   
using namespace std;
char *ipAddrFromInterface(char *apInterfaceName) //this function is not from me
{
     return "255.255.255.255";
    /*char *if_name = (char *) apInterfaceName;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    size_t if_name_len=strlen(if_name);
    if (if_name_len<sizeof(ifr.ifr_name)) {
        memcpy(ifr.ifr_name,if_name,if_name_len);
        ifr.ifr_name[if_name_len]=0;
    } else {
       printf("interface name is too long\n");
    }int fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    if (fd==-1) {
        printf("A => %s\n",strerror(errno));
    }if (ioctl(fd,SIOCGIFADDR,&ifr)==-1) {
        int temp_errno=errno;
        close(fd);
        printf("B => %s\n",strerror(temp_errno));
    }
    if (ioctl(fd,SIOCGIFADDR,&ifr)==-1) {
        int temp_errno=errno;
        close(fd);
       printf("C => %s\n",strerror(temp_errno));
    }
    close(fd);

    struct sockaddr_in* ipaddr = (struct sockaddr_in*)&ifr.ifr_addr;
    return inet_ntoa(ipaddr->sin_addr);*/
}

struct socketData
{
    int sock;
    sockaddr_in  socket;
    char *interfaceName;
};

void print(int i)
{
    printf("%d\n", i);
    fflush(stdout);
}

void server_receive_thread(vector<char*> aInterfaceList)
{
    int socketIndex = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in  localSock;
    int socketDescriptor; int socketLength;

    vector<socketData> aSockets;
    for(; socketIndex < aInterfaceList.size(); socketIndex++)
    {
        socketData socketD;
        char *apInterfaceName = aInterfaceList.at(socketIndex);
        if((socketDescriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
        {
            printf("can't listen on interface %s... sleeping\n", apInterfaceName);
        }
        else
        {
            memset(&localSock, 0,  sizeof(localSock));
            localSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
            localSock.sin_port = htons(PORT);

            inet_aton(ipAddrFromInterface(apInterfaceName), &localSock.sin_addr);

            setsockopt(socketDescriptor, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, apInterfaceName, sizeof(apInterfaceName));
            if(bind(socketDescriptor, (struct sockaddr *) &localSock, sizeof(localSock)) == -1)
            {
                printf("can't bind interface %s to listen on port %d... sleeping\n", apInterfaceName, PORT);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("bound to interface %s on port %d\n", apInterfaceName, PORT);
                socketD.sock = socketDescriptor;
                socketD.socket = localSock;
                socketD.interfaceName = apInterfaceName;
                aSockets.push_back(socketD);
            }
        }
    }

            fd_set master;
        int fdMax = -1;
        while(1)
        {
                FD_ZERO(&master);
                for(int iSock = 0; iSock < aSockets.size(); iSock++)
                {
                        socketData d = aSockets.at(iSock);
                        FD_SET(d.sock, &master);
                        if(d.sock > fdMax)
                        {
                                fdMax = d.sock;
                        }
                }
                printf("fdmax is : ");
                print(fdMax);
                if(select(fdMax+1, &master, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1)
                        print(2);
                print(200);
                for(int iSock = 0; iSock < aSockets.size(); iSock++)
                {
                        socketData d = aSockets.at(iSock);
                        if(FD_ISSET(d.sock, &master))
                        {
                                print(3);
                        }
                }
                print(1);
        }


}

int main()
{
std::vector<char*>  interfaceList;
interfaceList.push_back("wlan0");
interfaceList.push_back("eth0");
server_receive_thread(interfaceList);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: So to confirm, it never prints out 2 or 200, 3 or 1?

Comment: Sounds like it isn't correctly binding or generally setting up the socket correctly. Have you tried temporarily getting it to bind to 0.0.0.0, if that works then you would know the problem is in setting up the listening sockets.

Comment: Did you verify that `ipAddrFromInterface()` is returning the correct IP, that `inet_aton()` and `setsockopt()` are not failing?

Comment: There's a lot of redundant code here. If you printed `errno` and then closed, you wouldn't need the temporary. If `fdMax` is intially zero you don't need to test it for zero.

Comment: theSmallNothing => No only "fdmax is :" and "bound to interface" also yes the ips are Correct

Answer (score 0):

Well, this line could certainly cause the observed misbehavior:

```
if(fdMax = 0 || d.sock > fdMax)
```

Since it's using the assignment operator (=) rather than the equality-test operator (==), it's setting fdMax back to zero every time the if-clause is evaluated.  That means that fdMax is not being calculated correctly and is thus too small, so some of your sockets are not being included in select's watched-sockets-set.

All you actually need to do there is:

```
if (d.sock > fdMax) fdMax = d.sock;
```

Another (minor) error is a bit earlier, here:

```
    int fdMax = 0;
```

that should be:

```
    int fdMax = -1;
```

(it's minor because it would only cause actual misbehavior in the case where your aSockets list is empty, which is probably an unlikely scenario, but for the sake of completeness it's better to have it correct)

Comment: Corrected in my edit, however I found that was not the problem but that I tried to read on an ip not the broadcast address (see my edit)